# Website without page view event and where All Click Element trigger doesn't work

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm working on a new wordpress website where there is no page view event. I've also tried to trigger a basic GA event tag based on all click elements and nothing happen... I've never seen this before. Tag assistant tell me that the TAG is well installed and actually it seems to be well installed...

I'm kind of lost here...

Here is the snippet :

```
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w<[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');
```

Here is my debugger :

[image]

Comment: Add please a screenshot of your GTM Tag.

Comment: what do you mean exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a typo in the GTM snippet :

The first line:

`<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w<[l].push({'gtm.start':`

should be

`<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':`